# Алгоритм scrollbar а JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

Всем привет я хочу разобраться в реализации скроллбара на JS и не могу разобраться в расчетах

```
scrollBar.style.top = content.scrollTop/(content.scrollHeight/content.clientHeight)+ 'px';
```

Вот этот код работает правильно но он работает с динамической высотой скроллбара
но как написать расчет при установленной min-height у скроллбара
Помогите пожалуйста, я хотел разобраться именно с голым js можно Jquery но не надо советовать плагины и библиотеки